Date added to Group
I've created this searchkit search of people who have been added to a Campaign Newsletter group.  I want to include the date they were added to the group, but I cant seem to work out how to do it. I'm sure its easy. Any help appreciated. Thanks
  "version": 4,
  "select": [
    "id",
    "title",
    "Group_GroupContact_Contact_01.display_name"
  ],
  "orderBy": [],
  "where": [
    [
      "title",
      "CONTAINS",
      "Campaign newsletter"
    ]
  ],
  "groupBy": [],
  "join": [
    [
      "Contact AS Group_GroupContact_Contact_01",
      "INNER",
      "GroupContact",
      [
        "id",
        "=",
        "Group_GroupContact_Contact_01.group_id"
      ],
      [
        "Group_GroupContact_Contact_01.status:name",
        "=",
        "\"Added\""
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "having": []
}```


Mike - unless there is something preventing you, pls add your comments as Comments, not as Answers so moderators don't need to clean up. thx

Join on Group Subscription Histories. It's Action Date.
EDIT: This version below should work with older versions of civi too.

{
  "version": 4,
  "select": [
    "id",
    "sort_name",
    "Contact_SubscriptionHistory_contact_id_01.group_id:label",
    "Contact_SubscriptionHistory_contact_id_01.status:label",
    "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Contact_SubscriptionHistory_contact_id_01.date) AS GROUP_CONCAT_Contact_SubscriptionHistory_contact_id_01_date"
  ],
  "orderBy": {},
  "where": [],
  "groupBy": [
    "id",
    "Contact_SubscriptionHistory_contact_id_01.group_id",
    "Contact_SubscriptionHistory_contact_id_01.status"
  ],
  "join": [
    [
      "SubscriptionHistory AS Contact_SubscriptionHistory_contact_id_01",
      "INNER",
      [
        "id",
        "=",
        "Contact_SubscriptionHistory_contact_id_01.contact_id"
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "having": []
}


Fantastic, thanks a lot. Would never have found that!

Sorry @Demerit - but how do i get the join date for just that group? When I do as you say, it pulls action dates for all the groups the person has joined. So I get tons of results!

You'll need to do a "group by", but also it looks like by default it doesn't join on contact id. I'll update my answer with a screenshot.

Thanks Demerit. Unfortunately I am not able to import your code. I tried to rebuild it but I dont have the value or field options available.

https://i.postimg.cc/NFRjbzhy/Screenshot-2024-06-03-095438.png

Ok you're on an older version of civi. I'll update the answer.

Thanks that worked!
